# NetApp ONTAP with Python netapp-ontap - create vault policy

Tags: python, netapp, ontap

I am trying to create a custom policy using netapp-ontap python library, version 9.11.1. I can do the same using the CLI `snapmirror policy create` as show [here](https://docs.netapp.com/us-en/ontap-cli-97/snapmirror-policy-create.html#description) where I can specify `-type vault`. I don't seem to see the way to do this using the Python library. I am assuming I should be using [SnapmirrorPolicy](https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMLP2858435/html/resources/snapmirror_policy.html) resource to do this but that does not allow me to specify type and just creates `mirror-vault` type.

Any ideas how could I get the custom vault policy created?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most elegant way to do this but for now I have done:

```
    cli = CLI()
    cli.set_connection(connection)
    response = cli.execute(
        'snapmirror policy create',
        body={
            'vserver': SVM_NAME,
            'policy': POLICY_NAME,
            'type': 'vault'
        }
    )
    response.poll()
```

still seeking for a better answer using the built in Python resource so if you know of a better way please post.